# Delphi dynamic array efficiency

Tags: delphi

I am not a Delphi expert and I was reading online about dynamic arrays and static arrays. In [this](http://www.drbob42.com/delphi/perform.htm) article I have found a chapter called "Dynamic v. Static Arrays" with a code snippet and below the author says:

> [...] access to a dynamic array can be faster than a static array!

I have understood that dynamic arrays are located on the heap (they are implemented with references/pointers).

So far I know that the access time is better on dynamic arrays. But is that the same thing with the allocation? Like if I called `SetLength(MyDynArray, 5)` is that slower than creating a `MyArray = array[0..4] of XXX`?

Comment: You could perform your test, but in general, allocation is almost always the bottleneck of any situation. I'm pretty sure the word "access" here refers to looking up one of the elements, rather than allocation. Since a dynamic array has an unknown number of elements, at any given point, you may need to allocate more. But a static array only needs it once. So really, it depends on how *you* need to use an array.

Comment: The test application you linked to is bogus.  The static array there is declared as a global variable so it exists in the application's data segment rather than on the stack.  The linked performance test is ridiculous - it doesn't do anything to eliminate other sources of latency.  Simply repeating or reversing the order of the tests changes the result.  The author doesn't have a clue.

Comment: @JerryDodge So the code I posted above is basically equivalent in terms of cost/efficiency because I am just initializing an array, correct?

Comment: Not really, I meant your two pieces of code aren't related to that particular comment you quoted from that article. That quote speaks about *accessing* the array, but your code is related to *allocating* the array.

Comment: Also, please beware, that article is comparing 16bit and 32bit!!! 16 bit does not even exist anymore!!! The author is also calling something RTTI which is not really RTTI. So personally, I don't trust that article.

Comment: I am a bit confused now. Dynamic arrays in general has a faster access speed but this does NOT imply a fast allocating time (?).

Comment: @EmmaRossignoli No, dynamic arrays do not have faster access at all. The article is wrong, the test he performed was bad, and the conclusions were fallacious.

Comment: It depends on how you use it. If you call `SetLength` once to the size you need, then it would theoretically be the same as a new static array. But the whole idea of using a dynamic array at all is that the size changes, and each time `SetLength` is called would thus be a bottleneck.

Comment: I don't think I'd trust the assertion that dynamic arrays can be access more quickly than dynamic arrays. My advice is to unlearn everything you thought you learnt from that article and pretend you never read it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Trust is not required, surely.  It's entirely a caching phenomenon.  In the quoted test the dynamic array was freshly allocated (and living in cache).  The static array had to be fetched from memory into cache since it was a global var and not living on the stack (which would naturally be cached).  Repeating the static array test subsequently (once it has been cached) returns equal performance to the dynamic array.

Comment: @J... I'm sure you are right.  I didn't look in detail.  I just rejected the nonsensical hypothesis.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Quite fair enough.

Comment: I read that article more as "This is the way **I** do things, so I'm going to do everything I can to convince my readers why they should do things the same way I do by telling them it's the *best* way." Even the very first line of the article is incorrect "Delphi is based on components". False - I've written plenty Delphi applications without a single component (besides the inevitable `Application` component). Also, looks like author has a hard time even counting to seven...

Comment: @Jerry The article is quite old now and Dr Bob is something of a celebrity

Comment: @Jerry: Dr. Bob Swart has been around for decades, writing code in OP long before it was called OP. And deriding his intelligence and knowledge based on a two-decade plus old article about a new capability (dynamic arrays) in Delphi 2 is hardly fair. Perhaps you weren't around at that point in time when the amazing new capabilities of Windows 95, 32-bit code and Delphi were introduced, but it's certainly not reasonable for you to derisively refer to the individual's intellect or knowledge based on that decades-old article. Shame. Do your research. Bob has done numerous Delphi seminars and

Comment: conferences and written (literally) hundreds of technical articles about Delphi and C++ Builder. He's also done many Delphi seminars all the way back to Delphi 1 at Borland and CodeGear conferences.

Comment: @Ken No doubt, I was just merely pointing out reasons why OP shouldn't be trusting everything written in that article. I also try not to reference names when pointing things like that out. Honestly, I don't care if it's the Dalai Lama, if something they said shouldn't be trusted, I point it out. I'm certainly not the only person here who has said not to trust what the author wrote. The inaccuracy of that article is the whole reason why OP is asking a question here in the first place.

Comment: @EmmaRossignoli - Take a look at this code that shows you how to determine which variable (array) is a pointer and which holds the actual data: https://github.com/GodModeUser/DemoCode/tree/main/DataTypes%20-%20SizeOf

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> So far I know that the access time is better on dynamic arrays.

That is not correct. The statement in that article is simply false.

> But is that the same thing with the allocation? Like if I called `SetLength(MyDynArray, 5)` is that slower than creating a `MyArray = array[0..4] of XXX`?

A common fallacy is that static arrays are allocated on the heap. They could be global variables, and so allocated automatically when the module is loaded. They could be local variables and allocated on the stack. They could be dynamically allocated with calls to `New` or `GetMem`. Or they could be contained in a compound type (e.g. a record or a class) and so allocated in whatever way the owning object is allocated.

Having got that clear, let's consider a couple of common cases.

**Local variable, static array type**

As mentioned, static arrays declared as local variables are allocated on the stack. Allocation is automatic and essentially free. Think of the allocation as being performed by the compiler (when it generates code to reserve a stack frame). As such there is no runtime cost to the allocation. There may be a runtime cost to access because this might generate a page fault. That's all perfectly normal though, and if you want to use a small fixed size array as a local variable then there is no faster way to do it.

**Member variable of a class, static array type**

Again, as described above, the allocation is performed by the containing object. The static array is part of the space reserved for the object and when the object is instantiated sufficient memory is allocated on the heap. The cost for heap allocation does not typically depend significantly on the size of the block to be allocated. An exception to that statement might be really huge blocks but I'm assuming your array is relatively small in size, tens or hundreds of bytes. Armed with that knowledge we can see again that the cost for allocation is essentially zero, given that we are already allocating the memory for the containing object.

**Local variable, dynamic array type**

A dynamic array is represented by a pointer. So your local variable is a pointer allocated on the stack. The same argument applies as for any other local variable, for instance the local variable of static array type discussed above. The allocation is essentially free. Before you can do anything with this variable though, you need to allocate it with a call to `SetLength`. That incurs a heap allocation which is expensive. Likewise when you are done you have to deallocate.

**Member variable of a class, dynamic array type**

Again, allocation of the dynamic array pointer is free, but you must call `SetLength` to allocate. That's a heap allocation. There needs to be a deallocation too when the object is destroyed.

**Conclusion**

For small arrays, whose lengths are known at compile time, use of static arrays results in more efficient allocation and deallocation.

Note that I am only considering allocation here. If allocation is a relatively insignificant portion of the time spent working with the object then this performance characteristic may not matter. For instance, suppose the array is allocated at program startup, and then used repeatedly for the duration of the program. In such a scenario the access times dominate the allocation times and the difference between allocation times becomes insignificant.

On the flip side, imagine a short function called repeatedly during the programs lifetime, let's suppose this function is the performance bottleneck. If it operates on a small array, then it is possible that the allocation cost of using a dynamic array could be significant.

Very seldom can you draw hard and fast rules with performance. You need to understand how the tools work, and understand how your program uses these tools. You can then form opinions on which coding strategies might perform best, opinions that you should then test by profiling. You will be surprised more often than you might expect that your intuition is not a good predictor of performance.

Comment: That last paragraph is the most crucial one to understand. While the rest answers the question, the last should be reconsidered every time one considers refactoring for performance.